# How to validate an input string using conditionally allowed strings?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I want to block some words from being used in a username unless they are a substring of a permitted string.

The words `love`, `hug`, and `kiss` are not permitted, unless they are used in `mylovely`,`givehug`,`kissing`.

I started with this pattern, but it doesn't work:

```
preg_match('[love|hug|kiss]', $data)
```

These are some inputs with the desired outputs:

- boolove (invalid - "love" found, but not in "mylovely")
- mylovely (valid - "love" contained in "mylovely")
- givehug (valid - "hug" contained in "givehug")
- igivehug (valid - "hug" contained in "givehug")
- kissing (valid - "kiss" contained in "kissing")
- youhug (invalid - "hug" found, but not in "givehug")
- ikiss (invalid - "kiss" found, but not in "kissing")
- Basit (valid - doesn't contain love, hug, or kiss)

How can I achieve this validation to return a true|false response?

Comment: Do you just want to match the unacceptable words as whole words? `preg_match('~\b(?:love|hug|kiss)\b~', $data)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, just even if there is half of it, but if word is matching to acceptable word, then ignore it.

Comment: Try `preg_match('~love(?!you)|hug(?!gy)|kiss(?!es)~', $data)` then, to match `love` but not `loveyou`, etc.

Comment: What about preg_match('/^(?=.*kiss\b)|(?=.*love\b)|(?=.*hug\b)/i', $data); I had good results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated my question because it was even confusing me. made it more clear of the objective with proper example.

Comment: You mean match any string but the `love`, `hug`, `kiss`? `'~^(?!(?:love|hug|kiss)$)~'`?

Comment: Your question is still confusing after the edit.  Wiktor's first pattern seems to be what you are looking for.  What are you _really_ looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I looking for any words that have love, hug and kiss anywhere in the word, but unless thous words are `mylovely`, `givinghug`,`kissing`

Comment: That's a rather arbitrary set of exceptions, don't you think?  What about `kisses` and `hugging` etc?  You have been with SO for 8 years, why are you struggling to ask this question?  Please post a few sample inputs that should be matched, a few that shouldn't be matched, and explain why.

Comment: You should re-phrase your question using regex terms ("match" or "do not match"). It is not possible to understand "I want to prevent some words to be saved as username", "(un)acceptable words" (regex matches a string or part of it, or not).

Comment: @mickmackusa, english is not my monther toung, thats why I get struggle to explain sometimes. I have added example with valid and invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My non-regex method has a potential flaw exposed when two `$flag` values exist, but one `$forgive` value exists, so I wish to provide a regex method that uses a pattern with lookbehinds and lookaheads to identify invalid strings:

Code ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d467b543944881b645778b93e74d522416665d18) , [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vedodz/1)):

```
$inputs=['love','mickmackusa','kisses','mylovely','give','hug','givehug','kiss','kissing'];
foreach($inputs as $input){
    echo "\n$input ";
    var_export(preg_match('/kiss(?!ing)|(?<!give)hug|(?<!my)love(?!ly)/i',$input)==1?false:true);
}
```

Output:

```
love false
mickmackusa true
kisses false
mylovely true
give true
hug false
givehug true
kiss false
kissing true
```

---

Old non-regex method...

Input:

```
$input='code'; // mylovely(true) , give(false) , code(true)
$checks=['love'=>'mylovely','give'=>'givehug','kiss'=>'kissing'];
```

Method (no regex):

```
$result=true;
foreach($checks as $flag=>$forgive){
    if(stripos($input,$flag)!==false && stripos($input,$forgive)===false){
        $result=false;  // unforgivable word included
        break;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Explanation:

- The `$checks` array has keys that represent words that *may* be invalid, and values that are permitted if the key is matched in the `$input` value.
- The 3 `$check` elements are iterated and `stripos()` is used to case-insensitively check for input validity.
- For efficiency, as soon as `$input` is deemed invalid, the loop is broken.

Comment: It is perfect, but I need to have final value is true or false for each single words.. since user will be providing one username only on signup  process

Comment: sorry, but only problem I see, if username is `mickmackusa` then it will still return invalid, since it is not matching the valids array.

Comment: `youhug` and `ikiss` should fail, but `mickmackusa` should not fail, since its not part of first array at all. I feel very stupid as I cant even describe this simple thing.

Comment: Thank you mick for your help

Comment: @Basit, my non-regex method was not good enough and made too many function calls.  I have provided a regex method that is superior.  Please use this, instead of my earlier method, in your project.